# BeautifulSoup Webscrape Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to Python and coding in general. I was following a video tutorial on webscraping on YouTube and I am having issues when trying to run my code.

What I am trying to do:

- I am trying to write a query to pull all of the front page deals from
  a website (CigarMonster.com) and pull 5 attributes (Cigar
  Description, Size / Qty Description, Original Price, Sale Price, and
  Percent Off) from each listing on the page. I would like to capture
  those in a CSV file.

What I have tried:

- I have been testing the code in Anaconda and I have each of the individual attributes grabbing the correct text/html.
- I cannot get the entire script to run. I get errors and I am not sure what is going on.

Below is the script:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#opens up connection and grabs the webpage
url = 'https://www.cigarmonster.com/'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_byte = urlopen(req).read()

webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')

#parses html
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")

# grabs each of the products
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"quickview-pop launchModal"})

filename = "cigar_list.csv"

f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "cigar_brand,product_size,famous_price, monster_price, percent_off"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    try:
        cigar_brand = container.find("div",{"class":"item-grid-product-title"}).text
    except Exception as e:
        cigar_brand = "NA"
    else:
        pass
    finally:
        pass

    size_container = container.findAll("span", {"class":"product-subtitle"})

    product_size = size_container[0].text

    famous_price_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"col-xs-12 item-grid-product-fss-price"})

    famous_price = famous_price_container[0].text

    monster_price_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"col-xs-12 item-grid-product-monster-price"})

    monster_price = monster_price_container[0].text

    percent_off_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"col-xs-12 item-grid-product-fss-pct"})

    percent_off = percent_off_container[0].text

    #print("cigar_brand: " +  cigar_brand)
    #print("product_size: " +  product_size)
    #print("famous_price: " + famous_price)  
    #print("monster_price: " +  monster_price)
    #print("percent_off: " +  percent_off)
    f.write(cigar_brand + "," + product_size + "," + famous_price + "," + monster_price + "," + percent_off + "\n")
 
f.close()
```

I get these errors when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cigar_monster_scrape.py", line 8, in <module>
    uClient = urlopen(uReq).read()
  File "C:\Users\nmbuc\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\nmbuc\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\nmbuc\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 547, in _open
    return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',
  File "C:\Users\nmbuc\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\nmbuc\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1421, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

I was also getting a fair amount indention errors at first too.

Comment: you should include the errors that you get at the bottom of your post

Comment: What if you tried to replace the `req` variable on row 8 to `url`

Comment: I wonder if it is related to my installation. Does anyone have sample soup code .py file I can try? I tried to run code that people said were working and still got similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your 2 below line of code and then you are good to go. In the below code i have used [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io) instead of **urlib** rest everything is same.

```
import requests   

url = 'https://www.cigarmonster.com/'
req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})    

#parses html
page_soup = soup(req.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Thanks Vin! This worked perfectly. It is able to pull now! I just need to make some changes to get it to go to the second page and move the first line down in the file...